# How could you use the same hidden input in multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

*I know this could be done with JavaScript quite easily, but I'm curious to know if there is any way to do it without it.*

I have a web page that contains multiple forms. They all change different properties of the same entity.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="FirstField" id="FirstField">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="SecondField" id="SecondField">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I also need to send the ID of the entity, so I can know which one to modify.
If I use HTML.HiddenFor() in both forms, it works, but my page has duplicate ID's.

Is there a way to use the one hidden input for multiple forms, without duplicating it or using JavaScript?

Comment: "to do it without it" is quite paradoxal. :)

Comment: Since they're all dealing with the same entity, why have separate forms?

Comment: just use a class on the hidden item.

Comment: @NathanMiller The entity has multiple properties, but we didn't want to update them all at once, so they were seperated in multiple forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same `input` in multiple `form`s, since an HTML element can't be inside two parent elements at once.

My actual problem here was that using MVC's HTML.HiddenFor() would create duplicate `id`s in the page.

The solution is to not use the HiddenFor helper method and instead add the hidden `input` manually. That allows you to specify a `name` attribute without having the `id` attribute.

The result would be something like this, which has no duplicate `id`s:

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="FirstField" id="FirstField">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="ItemID">
    <input type="text" name="SecondField" id="SecondField">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```